# How To Programmatically Check Tumblr Username Availability?

Tags: tumblr

is there any way to check for username availability for tumblr? i want to check if a username is available to register on tumblr.

I tried checking HTTP response of urls like username.tumblr.com but the one that returns 404 are still not available for registration. Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I got:

```shell
curl 'https://www.tumblr.com/svc/account/register' --data 'user%5Bemail%5D=x@apple.com&tumblelog%5Bname%5D=USERNAMETOCHECK&form_key=!1231473848212%7CKpTkShMIsrNRL3V1GPCfNlpw6V8&action=signup_account'
```

**BUT:**

- It's not a public API so your IP might be blocked or it might just stop working without notice.
- the `form_key` parameter might expire after a little while; you should be able to parse that from `https://www.tumblr.com/` to get a new one.

Notes:

- I found this request from the registration screen in Chrome's developer tool, "copied it as CURL", and removed everything that wasn't necessary.
- `x@apple.com` is just the shortest non-used email address I could think of.
- The response will be something like:

  ```
  {
     "redirect": false,
     "redirect_method": "GET",
     "errors": [
        "Someone beat you to that username.",
        "You forgot to enter your password!"
     ],
     "signup_success": false,
     "next_view": false,
     "usernames": [
        "..."
     ]
  }
  ```

  If `Someone beat you to that username.` is present in the errors, then the username is taken.

---

Your alternative is using one of the [many services and APIs](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+username+available) that probably do the same thing.